# Visual Studio deployment error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone

"The application could not be launched for debugging. Please make sure the device is unlocked."

I am getting this error when I try to launch the app on my device for debugging.

I have tried the following:
Relaunch Visual Studio,
Reinstall Visual Studio,
Restart my computer,
I have selected both debug and release in the configuration window.

The problem is that its not getting launched even in the emulator. The emulator opens and never loads the app but gives the same error message. And I have tried to just open a new application on VS and tried to run the default application. That also gives the same problem.

Everything was working fine after I opened a few more projects for reference, It suddenly started giving this error message.

Comment: First Clean the Solution & try to re debug

Comment: I tried that. But problem not sovled.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure a Windows project is not set as startup(assuming you have both windoes project and phone project in the same solution). For example If your target platfrom is a Windows phone project WP7, then you cannot have a windows project as startup. This is a known reason for the error you mentioned.

Also what is the operating system you are working with? I know the error you mentioned reprorted on some OS's including Windows server 2003 and 2008. Try running your project in winsdows 7.

Comment: I have no project set at startup. And I am running windows 8.

Comment: Can you clarify what is the target platform here?

Comment: right click on project properties and then on devices tab check the target device setting.

Comment: I tried with Device and Emulator 7.1.. Both give the same error

Comment: When I try with Device the status message says Launching TaskHost.exe and gets stuck there.

Answer (score 0):

I suddenly got exactly the same issue today. I was coding like always and then I got this problem.

```
// P.S.
// Today I updated Windows from 8 to 8.1
// Then I installed VS 2013 preview
// But continued working in VS 2012 (I need R#)
// After ~ 5 hours of work I got this issue
```

I tried everything, deleted emulators from Hyper-V, deleted all virtual commutators, restarted VS 2012, restarted laptop, deleted `Bin` and `obj` folders from project, rebuilded project.

But nothing helped.

*Then I tried to open solution in VS 2013 preview, and it works!!*

I hope I help you with this answer.

If somebody know how to fix it in VS 2012, please tell us

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem but I’m able to debug my app once I click OK on the error prompt following the “Launching TaskHost.exe failed.” message in the status bar. I haven’t been able to solve it but I’ve found a workaround that might also work for you.

Start the “Simulation Dashboard” under “Tools” and instead of starting the debugger the usual way build your project if needed and then try to start the debugger by clicking “Locked” under “Lock Screen” on the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23772426/5675763) worked for me.

Under the following:

```
Solution(Right-click) > Properties > Configuration Properties > Configuration
```

Ensure that your main project is set to 'Deploy.'