# DeviceNotFoundException in VS 2013 for WP Unit Test Project

Tags: windows-phone-8, vs-unit-testing-framework, visual-studio-2013

I have a solution with two Windows Phone 8 projects. One is the application, second is Windows Phone 8 Unit Test Project.

Problem is that **I can not run any test from test project**, it builds normally, then I caught DeviceNotFoundException:

```
Exception of type 'Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.DeviceNotFoundException' was thrown.
```

But application project is running normally.

I tried to delete emulator from Hyper-V, checked project run/debug configuration, but nothing helped.

On VS 2012 I was able to run WP8 Unit Test Project, but my VS 2012 now can not even [run my projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064095/visual-studio-deployment-error/17347372#17347372)...

**UPD:**
If I set test project as start project, and then try to debug it, I got:

[image]

I tried to create new solution with just new empty Windows Phone 8 Unit Test App, and got this error again, and emulator even not starting...

Comment: Since VS2013 is still in preview, I suggest filling a bug report on Microsoft Connect (or on the MSDN forums)

Comment: I understand that VS 2013 is preview, but my VS 2012 not working too, with another problem ;( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064095/visual-studio-deployment-error/17347372#17347372

Comment: I just have posted same question on MSDN forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/45768e91-52aa-4b02-805f-0c7d8f9845bc/vs-2013-preview-windows-phone-8-test-app-project-can-not-be-run