# Launching TaskHost.exe failed, trying to run Windows Phone 8 app?

Tags: windows-phone-8, deployment, visual-studio-2013

My VS 2013 setup has been humming along fine for months now. Today I tried to update to Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 RC.  Just like last time when I updated to Update 1, setup failed badly with a huge list of packages marked with the "Incorrect Hash Value" error.  Unfortunately MS does not have an ISO yet for Update 2 so I can't take that route to complete the update like I did last time.  Now I can't run apps on the Windows Phone emulator or on the phone (device) anymore.

I believe that the failed update caused my current deployment problems since the problem surfaced right afterwards.  It could be due to some other NuGet package or Extension, but the update is the most likely cause due to the timing of events.

I did extensive reading on SO and tried all the noted solutions.  None of them worked:

- cleaned and rebuilt the test Windows Phone 8 project (multiple times)
- restarted VS2013
- rebooted
- Exited VS 2013 and restarted it with the Emulator left open (for the Emulator test)
- repaired the Windows Phone Emulator install
- repaired the VS2013 install

Nothing works.  After the IDE installs the app on to the emulator, I still an error dialog box saying:

"The application could not be launched for debugging.  Ensure that the target device screen is unlocked and that the application is installed."

And in the VS2013 IDE status line I see the message: "Launching TaskHost.exe failed".

Does anyone know how to fix this?  Note, I tried several WP8 projects that I know worked successfully before and none of them can deploy successfully anymore to either the Emulator or the Device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see this was asked a month ago, but I had this issue as well. If I left the Emulator running and tried launching it again, I would have TaskHost fail with a different error.

The following was what made it work for me.

Under the following:

```
Solution(Right-click) > Properties > Configuration Properties > Configuration
```

Ensure that your main project is set to 'Deploy.'

Answer (score 1):

Have many reason to error.! So, If you doing with database such as SQLLite file or SQL compact file for your project WP, you should check it is used anywhere. Or choose Embed source copy in visual. That's my fail.And i fixed ok!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try from the menus?

- `BUILD > Rebuild Solution`

That worked for me just now.